# how to GET local file information with fetch API for a firefox extension

Tags: firefox, xmlhttprequest, firefox-addon, fetch, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am attempting to import a local csv file into my firefox extension background.js script. 
So far my script looks like this:

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080/folder1/myFile.csv').then(function(response) {
// Convert to JSON
return response.json();
}).then(function(j) {
// `j` is a JavaScript object
console.log(j);
});


fetch(request).then(function() { /* handle response */ });
```

And I cant seem to get anything console.log-ed. Should I use another method to get my csv as an object?

Also, I am using firefox developer edition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> // Convert to JSON
> return response.json();
> ```

The `json()` method converts **from** JSON, not to JSON. [JSON and JavaScript objects are not the same thing](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)!

You need a CSV parser. Browsers do not come with one built-in, but there are plenty of third-party libraries. Google turns up [Papa Parse](https://www.papaparse.com/) and [CSV.js](https://github.com/okfn/csv.js/).

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to give your addon permission to access the "localhost" domain. Otherwise, any `fetch` or `XMLHttpRequest` you'll make will fail because of Cross-Origin Request policy. You can do this by adding this permission in your addon `manifest.json`:

```
...

"permissions": [
  "*://localhost/*"
]
```

See the MDN page about [manifest.json permissions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/permissions) for more details about this.

Also, you'll have to make sure that your localhost server is properly configured to serve the file, of course.